# How should I store a time_t timestamp to a file using C?

Tags: c, file, datetime, file-io, time

For a small todo program that I am writing, I have timestamps that are of this form

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
```

and are saved every time a task is entered to denote the time that it was entered.

I want to store the tasks to a plain text file, so that the state can be saved and restored. How should I store the timestamps to the text file and how should I get them back in my program after reading the text file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Convert the `time_t` to `struct tm` using `gmtime()`, then convert the `struct tm` to plain text (preferably ISO 8601 format) using `strftime()`. The result will be portable, human readable, and machine readable.

To get back to the `time_t`, you just parse the string back into a `struct tm` and use `mktime()`.

For reference:

- [gmtime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html)
- [strftime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html)
- [strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)
- [mktime](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html)

Code sample:

```
// Converting from time_t to string
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *ptm = gmtime(&t);
char buf[256];
strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%F %T", ptm);
// buf is now "2015-05-15 22:55:13"

// Converting from string to time_t
char *buf = "2015-05-15 22:55:13";
struct tm tm;
strptime(buf, "%F %T", &tm);
time_t t = mktime(&tm);
```

Comment: @simpleBob: There are only three function calls and they're all well documented at the provided links. Have you tried using them? Did you run into any specific problems?

Comment: I was just wondering how to get encode it back to time_t after using `strftime()`. But I found `strptime` already. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The **portable** way is using the `difftime` function. Compute the `time_t` for a chosen epoch using `mktime`, then use `difftime` to compute the difference in seconds. To convert back, you can start with the epoch as a `struct tm` and add the number of seconds to `tm_sec`, then call `mktime` to get a `time_t`.

The **sane** way is to assume `time_t` is represented as seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 GMT) and convert to a large integer type (`long long` is best) to print it. POSIX requires `time_t` to be seconds since the epoch, and on any sane system it will be.

Comment: I did the first of your suggestions, as I need to cope with cross compiler and cross platform considerations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of unportable assumptions, just cast `time_t` to `long` (`long long` if you have a C99 compiler), write the `long` value, read the value and cast back to `time_t`.

The Standard makes no guarantee that a `time_t` is even representable as a long: it only says `time_t` is a arithmetic type, but the trick above should work for all sane systems :-)